# JDPicker Regex for mm/dd/YYYY format

Tags: jquery, regex, datepicker

I am using this script: http://jdpicker.paulds.fr/?p=doc 
It's a great datepicker, but of course, the guy didn't add "mm/dd/YYYY" as one of the formats.

He claims "You can modify or add some new options by editing the switch located between lines 71 and 109. You just need to use a few regexp and some brain cells !" - well, i'm not the best with regex and I can't get this working right.

My code:

```
case "mm/dd/YYYY": 
this.reg = new RegExp(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/); 
this.date_decode = "new Date(parseInt(matches[2]-1), matches[3], matches[1]);"; 
this.date_encode = 'this.strpad(date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + this.strpad(date.getDate()) + "/" + date.getFullYear();';
this.date_encode_s = 'this.strpad(date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + this.strpad(date.getDate())';
break;
```

This was an example of a working, YYYY/mm/dd format:

```
case "YYYY/mm/dd": 
default: 
this.reg = new RegExp(/^(\d{4})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})$/); 
this.date_decode = "new Date(matches[1], parseInt(matches[2]-1), matches[3]);"; 
this.date_encode = 'date.getFullYear() + "/" + this.strpad(date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + this.strpad(date.getDate());'; 
this.date_encode_s = 'this.strpad(date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + this.strpad(date.getDate());'; 
break;
```

Even after modeling after this, I couldn't get it to work. It formats the date properly, but ends up changing the calendar to the year 2038 for some reason. Any help would be great!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PSEVj/ - a working example.

Comment: `eval(this.date_decode)` a reason not to use this date picker :)

Comment: Oh wow, interesting. Do you have any better suggestions? I'm kind of bummed because I've been working with this one for hours and I've run into just this one problem.

Comment: **I love when someone asks specifically for regex and then accept non-regex solution.**

Comment: I wasn't sure if the problem was with the regex or the rest of the code. I am implementing "og Grand's" (user below us) new  regex string.

Comment: @Darius With "some" extra work this could be re-written to work without `eval` but that isn't done in 5 minutes (at least for me^^). So just stick with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change this line:

```
this.date_decode = "new Date(parseInt(matches[2]-1), matches[3], matches[1]);";
```

to this:

```
this.date_decode = "new Date(matches[3], parseInt(matches[1]-1), matches[2]);";
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides of `02/29`, all dates from year `2000` can be validated with regex pattern

```
(?:02\/(?:(?!00)[01]\d|2[0-8])|(?:0[469]|11)\/(?:(?!00)[0-2]\d|30)|(?:0[13578]|10|12)\/(?:(?!00)[0-2]\d|3[01]))\/2\d{3}
```

Answer (score 0):

And to look like a real programmer change your regexp to this

```
this.reg = new RegExp(@"^\d{4}/(\d|1[0-2])/(\d|(1[\d])|(2[\d])|3[0-1])$");
```